# I want to change the size of the chakra ui drawer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I'm using chakra ui and I want to set the width of the drawer component to `370px`.
I want to set the width of the drawer component to `370px`. If I pass `sm` or `lg` as the size, it will change the size to the default setting, but I can't change it to the size I want.

https://chakra-ui.com/docs/overlay/drawer

```
  <Drawer
    isOpen={isOpen}
    placement="right"
    onClose={onClose}
    finalFocusRef={btnRef}
    size="lg"
  >
```

Comment: You can try to define your own theme for the Drawer component and set up ur custom size. https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/customize-theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the dialog props i.e maxW

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Drawer: {
      parts: ['dialog', 'header', 'body'],
      variants: {
        primary: {
        secondary: {
          dialog: {
            maxW: "220px",
            
          }
        }
      },  
    },

});
export default theme;
```

Then use it on the Drawer component

```
<Drawer  variant="secondary"  placement={placement} onClose={onClose} isOpen={isOpen}>
```

Answer (score 7):

Ideally a new 'size' should be added to the theme and use the new size for `<Drawer/>`. This works alright when sidebar width is fixed (but custom).

However, if sidebar width is dynamic (set by dragging the sidebar edge or for some other reason) you need to set sidebar width manually.

One way is to add `w={customSidebarWidth}` and `maxW={customSidebarWidth}` to `<DrawerContent/>`. Also consider removing padding on `<DrawerBody/>`.

```
...
<DrawerContent w={customSidebarWidth} maxW={customSidebarWidth}>
    ...
    <DrawerBody p={0}>
        ...
        ...
    </DrawerBody>
    ...
    ...
</DrawerContent>
...
```